# Is there a way to locate my button based on the right edge of my form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to have two buttons always on the right side of my form. Is there a way to locate them based on their distance from the right edge instead of the left?

I've looked through the properties but didn't see anything. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: r u using winforms / wpf ?

Comment: I am using winforms.

Comment: There are two ways to do this, but it is not clear which of the two you mean. Do you want to re-adjust the position of these buttons if the window is resized? In that case, you'll have to get each button's "Anchor" information as indicated in the answer you've received. Or, are you looking to locate these buttons during design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the button to the right side of the form and set the button's `Anchor` property:

```
Anchor = Top, Right
```

Comment: Thanks, that did what I wanted. I was looking to keep the buttons on the right hand side as the window was resized. thanks!

Comment: @Jason When you find the answer of your question, you can kindly mark it as accepted by click on check mark at left side of answer. This way it will be more helpful for other users. You can accept only one answer while you can vote up as many answers as you find helpful, including the accepted one, by click on up arrow at left side of answer.